# How to revive plant whose base is mostly dead, but with one thriving section?

Tags: houseplants, plant-health, plant-care

I have a couple of plants (one Asplenium oblongifolium, one Calathea Louisae Freddy) which were once medium sized plants, but through neglect, most of their stems died. As a result, there is a big base with the stumps of many old dead stems, and just a couple of (very healthy and actively growing) stems. The Asplenium has been stuck in this state for a year or two now, with three fronds - occasionally a new one grews, but then sometimes one of the old ones dies.

I'd like to get the whole plant growing healthily again. What should I do? Do I cut off the dead bits so it has room to grw?